# Python3 and tkinter GUI button to open a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a program that uses PIL to examine an image and return the size, amount of colors, dpi, and so on, but now I want to put my code into a GUI system to help the user.

I have used `askopenfilename()` in a function, but I am running into an issue when trying to open a new file. I have the function run after the program starts and it lets me select a file and works just fine. When I click the button to open a new file, it lets me select a new file but it does not change any of the displayed information.

How can I refresh the screen with new information after a new file is selected? Here is the code I have:

```
def openPattern():
    global fileName
    path = askopenfilename()
    fileOpen = open(path, 'r')
    fileName = os.path.basename(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Art Intake | Developer Build")
    ms = MainScreen(root)
    ms.config(bg="grey")

    openPattern()
    pattern = Button(ms, text="Choose a file", command=openPattern,   
                highlightbackground='grey')
    pattern.pack()
    pName = Label(ms, text="Pattern Name: " + str(fileName), 
                 bg='grey')
    pName.pack()

    read = Button(ms, text="ReadMe", command=openRM, 
              highlightbackground='grey')
    read.place(rely=1.0, relx=1.0, x=-25, y=-15, anchor=SE)

    quit = Button(ms, text="Quit", command=ms.quit, 
             highlightbackground='grey')
    quit.place(rely=1.0, relx=1.0, x=-25, y=-45, anchor=SE)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: show code. without code it is too broad question. BTW: maybe you get some error message and it doesn't work - so run it in console/termina/cmd.exe/powershell

Comment: show [minimal, but complete](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code. And edit your answer, don't post code in the comments.

Comment: please, edit question and add code. Comment is not good place for code.

Comment: @furas I have ran it in terminal, but no error message shows up.  It acts like everything is running fine.

Comment: you have to update text in `pName`. `fileName` is normal variable  - not StringVar` - and it will no update text in `pName` automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At start you run `openPattern()` before label `pName` is created and label has `fileName` to display. But later you have to manually change text in label.

```
    pName['text'] = "Pattern Name: " + fileName
```

First I create empty label and later I run `openPattern()` so it can update text in existing label. When I click button then `openPattern()` does the same - it updates text in existing label.

(not tested because code was incomplet)

```
def openPattern():
    path = askopenfilename()
    fileOpen = open(path, 'r')
    fileName = os.path.basename(path)

    pName['text'] = "Pattern Name: " + fileName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Art Intake | Developer Build")

    ms = MainScreen(root)
    ms.config(bg="grey")

    pattern = Button(ms, text="Choose a file", command=openPattern,   
                highlightbackground='grey')
    pattern.pack()
    pName = Label(ms, bg='grey')
    pName.pack()

    read = Button(ms, text="ReadMe", command=openRM, 
              highlightbackground='grey')
    read.place(rely=1.0, relx=1.0, x=-25, y=-15, anchor=SE)

    quit = Button(ms, text="Quit", command=ms.quit, 
             highlightbackground='grey')
    quit.place(rely=1.0, relx=1.0, x=-25, y=-45, anchor=SE)

    openPattern()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This fixed my issues and right now it works beautifully.  Thank you.